# What is the base cost for research?

Tags: eve-online

With the new industry changes to eve online, what can one expect to see as the "base" cost for research at a player owned starbase in a relatively non-busy system for these activities?

- Copying
- Invention
- Time research
- Material research

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is, the base price is the same, whether in a POS or in station. The difference in prices is due to NPC taxes (flat +10% cost, not reduced by standings).

The main difference between station industry and POS industry is not the job prices, but the material reduction when stacking industry-related POS modules. *(Up to 15% materials reduction for SuperCaps, to 27% reduction for small ships. The rest of the max reduction value is between those two.)* **[See EDIT]**

More accurate info may be found in the Dev Blogs: read them all.

---

**[EDIT]** Found more information in the [Crius v1 patch note](http://community.eveonline.com/news/patch-notes/patch-notes-for-crius):

Assembly Arrays have been overhauled:

- All assembly arrays now have a 2% material reduction to manufactured products (except for the Drug laboratory, Subsystem System Array, Rapid Equipment Assembly Array and Supercapital Assembly Array). Assembly Arrays will keep their 25% time reduction.
- Advanced Assembly arrays no longer 10% have material waste. They now all have 2% material reduction like their regular counterparts. Rapid Equipment Array material waste now is 5% instead of 20%.

A Thukker Component Assembly Array has been introduced:

- It gives a 25% reduction in manufacturing time and 10% reduction in required materials.
- Can only build Capital Construction Components and Advanced Capital Construction Components.

---

Source: [Dev Blog: Industry prices revamp in Crius](http://community.eveonline.com/news/dev-blogs/the-price-of-change/)
Source: [Dev Blog: POS revamp in Crius](http://community.eveonline.com/news/dev-blogs/starbase-changes-for-crius/)